# Skeletonize vectors in QGIS/Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, grass-gis, qgis-2.10, skeleton

I am trying to find a tool to create a skeleton of a large vector dataset using QGIS and its bundle. It should be directly programmatically callable through Python or commandline (QGIS, GRASS, OGR etc. are all okay).

The target is a large thin polygon with holes representing street areas and I need to obtain an approximation of the road network via skeletonization.

What I found so far:

- GRASS 7.0 has `v.skeleton` which should be good enough but does not seem to be in for integration with QGIS in the near future.
- CGAL has skeletonize algorithms, of course, but the Python support is very poor.
- pySkeleton does not work for me and I probably don't have time to salvage the code.

Other alternatives (openJump skeletonizer, [this old ArcGIS plugin](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/createCenterlines.htm)...) cannot be easily plugged into QGIS/Python.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: GRASS 7.0 **is** "directly programmatically callable through Python or commandline", so why must your solution also be so tightly bound to QGIS? Also, what about PostGIS? How is your data stored?

Comment: I'd like to post the solution as a directly usable QGIS plugin - therefore I'd like to stick to the GRASS version bundled by QGIS.

Answer (score 6):

This document ["Skeletonizing Polygons
Using PostGIS"](http://www.greenwoodmap.com/presentations/WyGEO-Casper-2015.pdf) describes a process which utilises tools from **PostGIS** and **GRASS**, both of which *might* be callable. It mentions using PostGIS to create a skeleton of the vectors and cleaning it up using either PostGIS again or GRASS.

There are existing tools from the *Processing Toolbox* which hopefully simplifies things when calling from Python/command line such as:

- [Import into PostGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database/importintopostgis.html#import-into-postgis) - use to import your dataset.
- [PostGIS execute SQL](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database/postgisexecutesql.html#postgis-execute-sql) - use to run the `ST_StraightSkeleton` function.
- [v.clean](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.clean.html) - use to run the `rmdangle` tool.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! However, I have to suppose that no PostGIS is installed...

Comment: @JanŠimbera - Most welcome buddy and good luck! Sounds like a very  interesting problem you have :)

Answer (score 4):

One, somewhat round-about option might be to use SAGA's grid skeletonization module (http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/imagery_segmentation_1.html), either through QGIS or using the command line `saga_cmd` utility. You'd have to convert your polygon to a SAGA raster first.

Otherwise, as stated by @Alpha-beta-soup, you could use `v.skeleton` from GRASS on the command line.

To use a commnand line tool from within Python, use the `subprocess` module to pass the command string to the system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'd rather not convert to raster as the extent is large and I need the result with a fine resolution; I'm thinking about that as a last resort option.