# Draw a centroid line through a line-like polygon feature?

Tags: qgis, vector

I have all these line segments travelling between points:

[image]

I want all the one close to each other to be merged into a single feature. So I dissolved them like so:

[image]

Now I just want one line travelling through the centre of each of these line-like polygons. Any functions that do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171145/skeletonize-vectors-in-qgis-python

Comment: Thanks, but I would say not. Skeletization kind of follows the contours of the dissolved polygons. I'm looking for something that cuts right through it y = mx +b style.

Comment: And https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33887/finding-centrelines-from-polygons-in-qgis

Comment: Find the centroid of the grouped vertices of the original line features for each polygon, split into each end, and join the centroids?

Comment: Some of these polygons look like very thin X or Y forms, so I guess your line will run down the middle of the arms of the X or Y, and not be inside the polygon at that point? Hence skeletonization is not the answer.

Comment: Yes exactly @Spacedman. Totally linear line. I don't think these solutions meant for roads and rivers are not necessarily what I want. I'll take what I can get though.

Comment: to get rid of the "arms", create a convex hull polygon over each of your polygon (or group of original lines), then you you can apply skeletization